# Why is my drawImage not accepting the '0+constant' for it's height param?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a vanilla JS Flappy Bird, and am trying to create the gap between `pipeTop` and `pipeBottom` by setting the height of `pipeBottom` to the height of `pipeTop` plus a variable that should serve as a gap.

I'm following a tutorial, and my code appears to be the same as that of the tutorials - though my pipe images overlap one another, instead of displaying with a gap.

[image]

```
// Canvas and getContext

var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');


// Load Images

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeTop = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();

bird.src = "images/bird.png";
bg.src = "images/bg.png";
fg.src = "images/fg.png";
pipeTop.src = "images/pipeTop.png";
pipeBottom.src = "images/pipeBottom.png";

// pipe vars

var gap = 100;
var constant = pipeTop.height+gap;

// Draw Images

window.onload = function draw() {

    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);

    ctx.drawImage(pipeTop, 100, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(pipeBottom, 100, 0+constant);
    ctx.drawImage(fg,0, cvs.height - fg.height);
};

draw();
```

`0+constant` should leave the height of the bottom pipe equal to the gap + pipeTop's height, but that's not the case. Instead, the bottom pipe is overlapping the top pipe. (pictured above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does things asynchronously, including loading images. If you set the `src` in code it doesn’t load the image immediately. Therefore `pipeTop.height` is zero when you set `constant`. You need to set it later when everything has loaded.

Comment: Thanks! Moved my `pipe variables` into the function that waits for an `onload`